# Match keyword with _ allowed in body but with __ signaling optional suffix

Tags: java, regex

I have a legacy application with a strange configuration key format that I've determined adheres to the following rule:

- The key can be any character (including _) of one or more length
- However, the key cannot end with a _ nor can it have __
- Except that __ can denote an optional suffix that will have only digits after it

some examples:

```
foo_bar__2  -- legal
_foo_bar__2 -- legal
foo         -- legal
foo--$%^##  -- legal
$%^#        -- legal
foo__42     -- legal
foo_        -- illegal
f__o__2     -- illegal
_           -- illegal
foo___2     -- illegal
foo__xzy    -- illegal
```

In my Java code, I got as far as `(.+[^_])(?:__(\\d+))?` but that has the problem that it does not capture the digit part. Instead, it captures the suffix as part of the key.

*For background `key__dd` indicates a k/v pair of a key to a number. `key` alone means that the default value is 1.*

Comment: Do you have to do this with a single regular expression?  Why not just `boolean valid = !key.endsWith("_") && (key.startsWith("__") || !key.contains("__"));`?

Comment: @VGR: That would still not apply all rules like optional `__` and digits in the end.

Comment: @anubhava You’re right, I misread the last bullet point.  But my point is that doing it all with a single regex is making things unnecessarily complicated.  So, what’s wrong with `boolean valid = !key.endsWith("_") && (!key.contains("__") || key.matches(".*__\\d+"));`?

Comment: It's refreshing to see a question that checks all the boxes: state the problem precisely and succinctly in words, provide examples (with expected results) for illustration when that would help the reader understand the question, and briefly show or explain what you have done to solve the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this regex for validating valid keys:

```bash
^(?:_?[^_\n]+)++(?:__\d+)?$
```

In Java:

```bash
final String rx = "^(?:_?[^_\n]+)++(?:__\\d+)?$";
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/3LxxpC/3)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `(?:_?[^_]+)++`: Match *optional*  `_` followed by 1+ of any character that are not `_`. Repeat this group 1+ times. `++` is possessive quantifier to make it more efficient without backtracking
- `(?:__\d+)?`: *Optionally* match `__` followed by 1+ digits before end
- `$`: End

---

Comment: Looks like no capture groups, but maybe to change to `([^_]+(?:_[^_]+)*)(?:__(\d+))?` should work?

Comment: also looks to be dropping key starting with _ like `_foo_bar__32`

Comment: ah I assumed no starting `_`, will edit the answer

Comment: You can remove anchors if you are using this regex in `.match` method to make it `_?[^_]+(?:_[^_]+)*(?:__\d+)?`

Comment: You don't need to wrap whole regex in a capture group, just use `.group()` to get the match.

Comment: It would seem you could simplify this to [`^(?:_?[^_]+)+(?:__\d+)?$`?](https://regex101.com/r/KqkfLm/1)

Comment: @Nick: Yes a good one, a slightly more efficient version would be: `^(?:_?[^_\n]+)++(?:__\d+)?$`

Comment: Indeed, that takes about half as many steps for the sample data.